# Is it possible to pass values to the params hash without putting the properties in a form in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I want to pass values to a rails controller method after a user submits a form in a Rails view.  I want the params hash structured as:

{:user => {:username=>"some name" }, :title => "My Title"}

To do this I use a hidden_field_tag outside the form element.  The generated html looks something like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="title" id="title" value="My Title" />


<%= form_for @user, :as => :user, :url => sign_in_path(@user) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :username %>
   #usual form field stuff
```

Yet, when I inspect the params hash, I only find the :username key and value pair inside.  Does this mean the title has to be part of the form via the "f.title" syntax?  I don't want to do this if possible because title is not part of the User model.  It's a separate property I want to use for something else inside the controller.

Comment: You need to put the `hidden_field_tag` inside the `form` and access it in the controller with `params[:title]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should include the hidden field inside your form for it to be included:

```
<%= form_for @user, ... do |f| %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :title, 'My Title' %>
  <%= f.input :username %>
  # And so on...
```

You should also use strong parameters as suggested, just as a general best-practice.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the title has to be part of the form in order to be submitted along with it.

You should use Rails 4 strong parameters if you don't want the `title` parameter in your `User` model.

```
class UsersController < ActionController::Base

  # your actions here

  private

  def person_params
    # don't permit the title paramter here.
    params.require(:user).permit(:username)
  end
end
```